# how to splice a subarray from returned data component vuejs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, array-splice

I have an object that is a list of arrays...

[image]

..this is a data declared in vue js from a prop:

```
    data: function(){
    return{
        listaSelezionati:this.selezionati
    }
}
```

..which is rendered on a v-for

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px;" v-for="(selezionato,index) in listaSelezionati">
```

..inside this for loop there is a button who calls a function

```
<div class="remove pull-right" v-on:click="rimuovi(index)"></div>
```

..with this function I want to splice the sub array of object "listaSelezionati" using "index", but I'm not sure how to do it..

here what I have tried:

```
    methods:{
    rimuovi : function(index){
        alert(index);
        return{
            this.listaSelezionati[index][0].splice(index,1)
        }
    }
}
```

but it does nothing, anyone have something to suggest?

**edit1**
I want to know if `return{this.listaSelezionati` should be a right approach to edit a component data

Comment: this.listaSelezionati[index][0] will point to sub array object. You are putting splice function on object.
Do you want to remove subArray at particular index?

Comment: Is there another `v-for` somewhere?

Comment: @BertEvans no is the only one, but there is a v-if before a v-for

Comment: And you want to remove one sub array?

Comment: @BertEvans yes, but also know if `return{this.listaSelezionati` is a right approach to modify a component da object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove an entire sub array by index all you need to do is this:

```
methods:{
  rimuovi : function(index){
    this.listaSelezionati.splice(index,1)
  }
}
```

There is no need to return a value; [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) updates the array it is called on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are going too deep into your arrays.

```
this.listaSelezionati[index]
```

is an array but

```
this.listaSelezionati[index][0]
```

looks like the first element of an array which is an Object.  So now it looks like you are splicing an Object at a position index.  This should produce an error.
I think you need:

```
rimuovi : function(outterIndex, innerIndex){
    alert(outterIndex, innerIndex);
    return{
        this.listaSelezionati[outterIndex].splice(innerIndex,1)
    }
}

<div class="remove pull-right" v-on:click="rimuovi(index, innerIndex)"></div>
// or
<div class="remove pull-right" v-on:click="rimuovi(outterIndex, innerIndex)"></div>
```

I haven't tested it, but at least it should get you closer

Comment: hmm... interesting, should i use the index to call outterIndex and innerIndex as well?